# Await in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-await, live

I am trying to go through the [Windows Phone Live tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx) but I get stuck when trying to implement the code example as it seems to be missing information.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Live;
using Microsoft.Live.Controls;

namespace WindowsPhoneCodeSample
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private LiveConnectClient client;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private async void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
                LiveOperationResult operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
                try
                { 
                    dynamic meResult = operationResult.Result;
                    if (meResult.first_name != null &&
                        meResult.last_name != null)
                    {
                        infoTextBlock.Text = "Hello " +
                            meResult.first_name + " " +
                            meResult.last_name + "!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        infoTextBlock.Text = "Hello, signed-in user!";
                    }
                }
                catch (LiveConnectException exception)
                {
                    this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error calling API: " +
                        exception.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
Error   2   The name 'await' does not exist in the current context  

Error   3   One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?
```

Am I missing some reference or something?

**Edit**

the tutorial seems to be poorly done or very out of date. I made a windows phone 8 application and it still does not build because of the "awai"t keyword.

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.


client.GetAsync is also a void method. So not sure how it returns something as well.
```

Comment: await and async are features of .NET 4.5. Is Windows Phone 7 using .NET 4.5?

Comment: @MailmanOdd: http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async

Comment: Hmm, I would think this tutorial would say I need a 3rd party package.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @chobo2: It's not 3rd party - it's from Microsoft. I'm still surprised it doesn't mention it though. Are you developing for Windows Phone 7.5, by the way?

Comment: Seems like a documentation oversight, I would suggest you provide feedback on that page--they probably just don't know.

Comment: Yea for 7.5 for now will eventually move to wp8(once I get my new phone in the next few months)

Comment: How about that other error. I am guessing WP does not support dynamic either right?

Comment: Yes, dynamic is not supported in WP7.x. I decided to go with two different implementations of skydrive manager for wp7 and wp8 because of this issue.

Comment: @SLaks I installed it but it does not detected the namespace to use. What is the using statement. I am not sure.

Comment: Never mind, I see the await keyword, It is something to do with the client.GetAsync("me") as it does not think it is a async method. It also seems to be a void statement too. Very confused right now(the tutorial must be very out of date or poorly done)

Comment: I just made a WP8 application and tried to put the code in and still fails on "Await" line The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Answer (score 0):

`await` works only with ***awaitables*** - see §7.7.7.1 on the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228593.aspx).

Since `client.GetAsync` is a void returning method, it can never be an ***awaitable***.

Comment: Yea, that's the conclusion I come to and that's why I am very confused with the tutorial.

Comment: According to the documentation of the [GetAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/live/hh534049.aspx "GetAsync method) of the [LiveConnectClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/live/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.aspx "LiveConnectClient class") returns `Task<LiveOperationResult>`. What version of the Live SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using version 5.5(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40739) that I got from following the link in the tutorial

Comment: The documentation on the link I provided is dated about 3 months. The samples in your link are dated about 2 years, as you can [see for your self](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/blame/master/Samples/WindowsPhone/LiveSDKAsyncAwaitSample/LiveConnectClientTaskAsync.cs). However the download on your link seems to be 4 moths old. (...)

Comment: (...) From that code you can learn two things: 1) bad naming hearts your users and; 2) how to implement a TPA (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern) on top of a EAP (Event-based Asynchronous Pattern). The Task-asynchronous methods in that class should have been suffixed TaskAsync since non Task-asynchronous methods suffixed async already exist.

Comment: hmm, where can I get a tutorial that fits wit the current version? I am just trying to learn how to sign people in and get basic information...that really my first step I want

Comment: Looking at the dates, I really don't know. From what you're asking, I'd say the SDK where I took that sample code would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install NuGet Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async (you can find it in NuGet Manager) so compiler recognize words await and async.
more info http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/